# How to add HTML elements before other HTML elements via a form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add HTML elements before some other HTML elements via a form using jQuery:

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="main-content">
    <h2 class="main-content-header">Projekte</h2>
    <div class="project-content">
      <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Haushalt</h3>
      <div class="project-wrapper">
        <div class="project-part">Rechnung1.doc <img src="icons/cross.png"><img class="preview-toggle" src="icons/preview.png"></div>
        <div class="project-part">Rechnung2.doc <img src="icons/cross.png"><img class="preview-toggle" src="icons/preview.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-content">
      <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Homepage</h3>
      <div class="project-wrapper">
        <div class="project-part">index.html<img src="icons/cross.png"><img class="preview-toggle" src="icons/preview.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-content-new">
      <h3 class="project-header"><img src="icons/plus.png">Neues Projekt</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The form:

```
<div class="new-content">
  <h2 class="new-content-header">Namenseingabe<img src="icons/cross.png" /></h2>
  <div>
    <form id="newName">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Projektname"/>
      <img id="savebtn" src="icons/save.png" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#savebtn').click(function() {
    var project = $('<div class="project-content">
      <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Test</h3>
      <div class="project-wrapper">
      </div>
    </div>');

    $('.project-content-new').before(project);
  });
});
```

I thought it should work this way, but it doesn't how can I achieve what I want to achieve?
I also tried to use the jQuery `.submit()` instead of the `.click()` function but that didn't work either.

I want to add a new `.project-content` element with all its content before the `.project-content-new` element.

Comment: Do you get errors in your console? You have to escape (or just concatenate) your new lines within strings, lest it be parsed as a new statement.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` this is the error the console gives me.

Comment: Concatenate your new lines, I.E. `ntent">' + /*new line*/ '<h3 `...

Comment: And I see what you mean with escaping the new lines. That fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your js code as follow and it should work just fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#savebtn').click(function() {
    var project = $('<div class="project-content">\
      <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn"\ src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn"\ src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Test</h3>\
      <div class="project-wrapper">\
      </div>\
    </div>');

    $('.project-content-new').before(project);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your jQuery code;

Working code is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#savebtn').click(function() {
    var project = $('<div class="project-content">      <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Test</h3>      <div class="project-wrapper">      </div>    </div>');

    $('.project-content-new').before(project);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
    <h2 class="main-content-header">Projekte</h2>
    <div class="project-content">
      <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Haushalt</h3>
      <div class="project-wrapper">
        <div class="project-part">Rechnung1.doc <img src="icons/cross.png"><img class="preview-toggle" src="icons/preview.png"></div>
        <div class="project-part">Rechnung2.doc <img src="icons/cross.png"><img class="preview-toggle" src="icons/preview.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-content">
      <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Homepage</h3>
      <div class="project-wrapper">
        <div class="project-part">index.html<img src="icons/cross.png"><img class="preview-toggle" src="icons/preview.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-content-new">
      <h3 class="project-header"><img src="icons/plus.png">Neues Projekt</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="new-content">
  <h2 class="new-content-header">Namenseingabe<img src="icons/cross.png" /></h2>
  <div>
    <form id="newName">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Projektname"/>
      <img id="savebtn" src="icons/save.png" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#savebtn').click(function() {
     var project = $('<div class="project-content">
    <h3 class="project-header"><img class="collapse toggleBtn"  src="icons/arrow_up_bl.png"><img class="expand toggleBtn" src="icons/arrow_down_bl.png">Test</h3>
     <div class="project-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>');

  $('.project-content-new').prepend(project);
   });
});
```